# how php code write if image values empty and stop the read in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need write a code if my images values is empty and stop the code read in codeigniter 
my code is as below

```
<?php foreach ($item['items'] as $key => $value): ?>
                         <li><a style="text-decoration:none;" data-fancybox="<?php echo $value['group']; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $value['images'][0]; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></a></li>
                        <div>
                            <?php  unset($value['images'][0]); ?>
                            <?php if (empty(!$value['images'])) :?>
                                <?php foreach ($value['images'] as $img): ?>
                                    <a data-fancybox="printer" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/products/<?php echo $img; ?>"></a>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**updated**
see my controller

```
'name' => 'Compatible Toners',
                    'group' => 'toners',
                    'images' => []
                    ]
                ],
```

when my images are empty I have following error

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'images'

Filename: pages/products.php

Line Number: 11
```

I need stop this error when my images are empty

Comment: if (!empty($value['images'])) :?>

Comment: your flase statement is wrong

Comment: what is correct way?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: See Kelvin's first comment, 
your statement: <?php if (empty(!$value['images'])) :?>
should be: <?php if (!empty($value['images'])) :?>

Comment: replace it but not fix error

Comment: than u need this <?php if (!empty(!$value['images'])) :?>

Comment: give your new false statement in your empty

Comment: wait a sec, your key "images" is always existed?

Comment: not  success it...

Comment: Use `@` to hide warnings `@$value['images'][0]`

Comment: Yadhu Babu comment is working